# Is it possible to run dusk on dev/staging/prod server?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-dusk

On the local machine, I am able to setup the dusk and run the test cases.
On Dev server, I am facing following issue.

> Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY"}}

Code(tests/DuskTestCase.php):

```
  public static function prepare()
    {
        static::startChromeDriver();
    }
protected function driver()
    {
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome(), 5000, 10000
        );
    }
```

Can anyone helps me to solve this issue? Or how to run dusk automation on dev server?

Comment: Please, post your `tests/DuskTestCase.php` content, to help.

Comment: localhost:9515 is the connection with the browser and has nothing to do with application URL on dev.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of localhost:9515 is the connection with the browser and has nothing to do with your application URL.

I need something to run dusk test cases on dev/prod server.

Answer (score 0):

Without exact errors and versions you use, it is hard to say what is not working on your end.

**DEV**

Here are some things you should take care of on your dev server:

1. Make sure you have proper `APP_URL` in `.env`
2. Make sure dusk is included for your dev environment in `composer.json`, and that it is in fact installed.
3. Start dusk test from console on dev server by `artisan dusk`
4. If it's not working, please post your errors, environment info and versions

**PRODUCTION**

Please note that you should never use dusk in production.

**AUTOMATION**

Use CI Tools for this.

You can read more, about it in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809695/laravel-dusk-test-for-remote-site-not-work/48814961#48814961)